# High-performance query of two tables with count from second table?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization

I am searching for a high-performance query using two tables to output all locations (name) from country (adm0 = 'DE') in the geodb_locations table, sorted in descending order by the number of users in the respective location

```
Table user
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| uid              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| plz              | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| freigeben        | tinyint(4)   | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+


Table geodb_locations
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(12)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name_url   | varchar(250) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| adm0       | char(2)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| adm1       | char(2)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


Desired result
+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
| name              | name_url          | useranzahl |
+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
| Berlin            | berlin            |       3165 |
| Hamburg           | hamburg           |       1623 |
| München           | muenchen          |       1146 |
| Köln              | koeln             |       1038 |
| Dortmund          | dortmund          |        693 |
| Dresden           | dresden           |        645 |
```

I have already tried the following query. However, the performance is very poor.

```
SELECT 
    geodb_locations.name, 
    geodb_locations.name_url,
    COUNT(user.uid) AS useranzahl 
FROM 
    geodb_locations 
LEFT JOIN
     user ON geodb_locations.id=user.plz
WHERE
    geodb_locations.adm0='DE' AND
    user.freigeben=1
GROUP BY 
    user.plz, 
    geodb_locations.name, 
    geodb_locations.name_url
ORDER BY 
    useranzahl DESC
LIMIT 25
```

**EDIT**

also tried COUNT with subselect and USE INDEX, results are same

```
SELECT 
    g.name, 
    g.name_url,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user u LEFT JOIN geodb_locations ON u.plz=geodb_locations.id WHERE freigeben=1 AND u.plz=g.id) AS useranzahl
FROM 
    geodb_locations g 
USE INDEX (adm0)
WHERE
    g.adm0='DE'
    
ORDER BY
    useranzahl DESC

LIMIT 25
```

Comment: which indexes do you have? you can try different index byy forcing them on the query see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html

Comment: pls see my edit section .. tried with USE INDEX .. still 2.5 sec .. without ORDER BY query works like expected ..

Comment: i don't know what adm0 or adm1 is actually. make a SHOW CREATE TABLE geodb_locations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected result by MySQL Optimizer for identical queries?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271758/unexpected-result-by-mysql-optimizer-for-identical-queries)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you posted this question twice? I don't see any big differences between this question and your other question _[Unexpected result by MySQL Optimizer for identical queries?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/271758/15356)_. Oh and welcome to DBA.SE.

Comment: no, only to make it clearer, perhaps there is a better solution / query to do the job